# How do I make my android apps fill the screen on Honeycomb?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-fragments

I just got a Xoom on Wednesday, and upon loading my apps onto it, they run in a small window, as if they are being run on a smaller device.

Various other apps fill the screen of the Xoom, although they don't seem to be using any specific honeycomb APIs, as they just seem to be the same UI I get on my phone, just stretched to fit.

How would I go about getting my apps to fill the screen? Do I have to use fragments, or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out:

I simply had to set the minSdkVersion in my manifest to 4 (1.6). This is because the SupportsScreens attribute of the manifest needed android:resizeable to be set to true. I could have set android:resizeable to true manually, but in API levels 4 and higher, it is set to true by default.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Comment: It is rather targetSdkVersion that enables this, which is set to be minSdkVersion if you don't specify it. You probably want to set it as high as possible to invoke default attributes on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

add this.

> supports-screens android:resizeable="true"

```
in manifest file so that your screen size be resizeable.
```