# supporting multiple screen sizes in android

Tags: android, screen-size

Hi I'm new to android world.Iam working on an application that supports multiple screen sizes i did as explained here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence . I didn't create different xmls for each screen size. But when I tested it on android 3 emulator it appears in small part of the screen.

[image]

So I think that the size specified for my application on the emulator is small so my widgets are not filling the whole screen as I want. Can I control that size of my application on the emulator?

Comment: You should add screenshots. You don't have permissions to put screenshots here, so upload them somewhere and add links here.

Comment: that is the snapshot http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/322/and3.jpg

Comment: Inserted screenshot into question.

Comment: hi , 
try to work with DP and not pixels

Comment: @inazaruk thanks alot for adding the pic :). @Houcine I've worked with DP not pixels but i didn't support minsdkversion=4 or higher  as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521233/how-do-i-make-my-android-apps-fill-the-screen-on-honeycomb. But when i did IT worked soooooooooooooooooooooooo well :). Thanks for trying to help me guys. I really appreciate that :).

Comment: visit this http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/01/plan-design-in-best-way-for-multiple.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this question...[How do I make my android apps fill the screen on Honeycomb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521233/how-do-i-make-my-android-apps-fill-the-screen-on-honeycomb)

Comment: you r THE GREATEST. I don't know how to thank u sir :).Thanks alot

Comment: I really tried but a box appears indicating that voting up needs 15 reputations :) I have only 1 :).So I can do nothing except thanking u :).

Answer (score 2):

Also, to avoid compatibility mode when running on Honeycomb, set `targetSdkVersion` to 11 or higher (as described at http://geekyouup.blogspot.com/2011/05/supporting-honeycomb-pt1.html).

Comment: Thank u sir.I appreciate that :)